# How to dynamically choose output parameter type in Spring MVC REST controller methods

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, parameters, bean-validation

I have a Spring MVC application which uses two `REST` methods to get a `Person` from the server, or to allow someone to remotely register. Both methods accept `JSON` and return it as well. The conversion to from `JSON` is handled in the `DispatcherServlet` of the application.

The two methods are:

```
// Gets a Person via REST.
@RequestMapping(value="/person/{personId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Person getPerson(@PathVariable("personId") String personId) {
    logger.info(RestController.class.getName() + ".getPerson() method called."); 

    return personService.get(Integer.parseInt(personId));        
} 

// Allows a new Person to register via REST.
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)    
public @ResponseBody Person postRegister(@RequestBody Person person, 
                                         BindingResult bindingResult) {    
    logger.info(RestController.class.getName() + ".postRegister() method called."); 

    // Validate Person.
    personValidator.validate(person, bindingResult);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

        /* NOTE: Messages object to be returned here. */

            List<ObjectError> errors = bindingResult.getAllErrors();            
            for (ObjectError error : errors) { 
                System.out.println(messageSource.getMessage(error.getCode(), null, null));            
            }
            return person;

    } 
    else {                       
        personService.insert(person);                                     
        return person;        
    }
}
```

These work perfectly well if there are no validation errors. But in the `postRegister` method, if there's a validation error(s), I want to return to the client a simple `Messages` object as follows:

```
public class Messages {

private List<String> messages;

public Messages() { 
    messages = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Which can then be converted to `JSON`.

So my problem becomes an issue of handling the return types from the methods. For a successful operation, I want each method to return a `Person`, but in the case of a failure, each method should return a `Messages` object.

Other than having both methods return a generic `Object`, is there a simple way that this 
can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could throw an exception in case the `BindingResult` has errors and then have a dedicated `@ExceptionHandler` for that method to return the messages instead:

```
@ExceptionHandler(YourValidationException.class)
public Messages handleIOException(ValidationException ex) {

    // Build up messages from BindingResult contained in the Exception
    return messages;
}
```